JPA console error in IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4
I try to select entity in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, but I get error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.json.bind.JsonbException PluginClassLoader(plugin=PluginDescriptor(name=Jakarta EE: Persistence (JPA), id=com.intellij.javaee.jpa, descriptorPath=plugin.xml, path=D:\Program Files\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4\plugins\JPA, version=241.18034.62, package=com.intellij.jpa, isBundled=true), packagePrefix=com.intellij.jpa., state=active) (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
I use OpenJDK 17. I asked the POE AI, and it tells me:
Add the followings to idea64.exe.vmoptions:
-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
-Djava.security.policy=d:/temp/my-security.policy

And create my-security.policy policy file with content:
grant {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};

It doesn't works for me. Please Help me.



I couldn't reproduce the issue on my side. Do you face the same problem with new sample project?
Please try to add dependency containing missing class to your pom.xml:

jakarta.json.bind
jakarta.json.bind-api
2.0.0


Please follow the related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-357192
